# How to add two maps of key to values(array) together in Presto?

Tags: presto

I have this presto query that gives me this.
[image]

but what I am looking for is this.

`{"accountnumber":"A00000065","invoice":{"ids":["2c92c09a693316310169384472126a0d"], "numbers":["INV00000270"]}}`

I have tried using the map_concat to no luck.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq5iu.png

---

**UPDATE**: If I do the following it works.

`map_concat(multimap_agg('number', invoice.invoicenumber), multimap_agg('id', invoice.id))`

but if I change to

`map_concat(multimap_agg('number', invoice.invoicenumber), multimap_agg('id', invoice.balance))`

I get this error

> line 1:23: Unexpected parameters (map(varchar(6),array(varchar)), map(varchar(2),array(decimal(18,6)))) for function map_concat. Expected: map_concat(map(K,V)) K, V

Comment: When you tried `map_concat`, what didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should go in a comment, but that's too long.
If it doesn't work, I'll delete the answer.

try this:

```
SELECT map_concat(multimap_agg('ids', invoice.id), multimap_agg('numbers', invoice.invoicenumber))
FROM ...
```

Comment: "message": "Invalid Query. Query failed (#20191114_170704_05485_qv264): line 1:23: Unexpected parameters (map(varchar(6),array(varchar)), map(varchar(2),array(decimal(18,6)))) for function map_concat. Expected: map_concat(map(K,V)) K, V"

Comment: map_concat(multimap_agg('number', invoice.invoicenumber), multimap_agg('id', invoice.balance))

Comment: You need to cast `invoice.balance` to `varchar`: `CAST(invoice.balance AS varchar)`.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was it.