# How to format presto api response as JSON using outputFormat and useIndexJoin?

Tags: presto

[How to add two maps of key to values(array) together in Presto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854077/how-to-add-two-maps-of-key-to-valuesarray-together-in-presto)

I can see the sample in the shared link. I need help with the implementation.

Comment: What is `outputFormat` and `useIndexJoin`? Can you please share sample data and desired output?

Comment: @GuruStron Right now my response is in the format of array for column headers and response. I need to write a wrapper code to map the header and response. 

However in the shared link, if you check the screenshot wherein they mentioned the output format as json and they got the response as desired without having to write a wrapper.

Comment: Can please share sample data (in text format) and expected result. The main thing in that question was fixing the query.

Comment: @GuruStron
sample data by using presto-cli: (response got in data callback function)
Data: [
  [
    16
  ]
] 
Columns:
[
  {
    name: 'Count_Transaction_Id',
    type: 'bigint',
    typeSignature: {
      rawType: 'bigint',
      typeArguments: [],
      literalArguments: [],
      arguments: []
    }
  }
]
Expected: 
[
  { Count_Transaction_Id: 16 }
]